# What is the derivative of the Dirac delta?

Tags: derivatives, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

The problem I'm having is how to find the gradient of delta.

Does the gradient do the following?

$$\nabla \delta(r)=\frac{\partial\delta(r)}{\partial x}\hat{x}+\frac{\partial\delta(r)}{\partial y}\hat{y}+\frac{\partial\delta(r)}{\partial z}\hat{z}$$

If that is correct, how do I derive delta of $r$ in respect to $x, y, z$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to start with the $1$-dimensional case?

Comment: Adam Merberg wrote an [answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-derivative-of-an-impulse-function/answer/Adam-Merberg) to that question on Quora.

Comment: Is $r$ supposed to be the position vector or the distance from origin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, that answer may be unsatisfying. The $\delta$-function is defined so that for a smooth functions $f$, we have that:
$$\int f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0)$$
So if you want to understand the derivative of the $\delta$-function, one can note that by integration by parts, and assuming that $f$ vanishes at infinity, you should have:
$$\int f(x)\delta'(x)dx=-\int f'(x)\delta(x)dx=-f'(0)$$
In general, you just define $\delta'(x)$ to be the function with this property on all smooth functions.

Edit: I'll compute $\nabla \delta$. Note that we have that:
$$\nabla \delta=\delta'(r)\hat{r}$$
This is a badly-behaved distribution in the following sense. Note that if $f(0,0,0)\neq 0$ then we formally have that:
$$\int\delta'(r) f(r,\theta,\phi)drd\theta d\phi= \delta(0)f(0,0,0)-\int \int\delta(r) \partial_r f(r,\theta,\phi)drd\theta d\phi$$
The latter is well-defined by the prior is not. On the other hand, we may write:
$$\int \delta'(r) f(r,\theta,\phi)drd\theta d\phi=-\int\delta(r) f(r,\theta,\phi)drd\theta d\phi-\int\delta(r) r\partial_r f(r,\theta,\phi)drd\theta d\phi=-f(0,0,0)$$

So you achieve the relation:
$$r\delta'(r)=-\delta(r)$$

Edit2:
To answer a point in the comments, there are two distributions with similar notation. One is defined by:
$$\int\int \int \delta(r)f(r,\theta,\phi)drd\theta d\phi=f(0,0,0)$$
The other is defined by:
$$\int\int \int \delta({\bf r})f(x,y,z)dxdy dz=f(0,0,0)$$

One has the formal relation:
$$4\pi r^2\delta({\bf r})=\delta(r)$$
I believe the the asker was interested in the prior, rather than the former.

Comment: so $\int x\delta'(x)dx=-\int\delta(x)dx=-1$?

Comment: yeah, exactly, you get it.

Comment: What would $\nabla\delta(r)$ be then? I didn't quite get that

Comment: This post has a few inaccuracies.  So, I thought it appropriate to clarify three points:  (i) The Dirac Delta is NOT a function.  (ii) The functionals that are written $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x)f(x)\,dx$ abuse notation and NOT integrals. Hence, integration by parts does NOT apply here.  (iii) For functional $\langle \delta',f\rangle$  , $f$ belongs to the space $C^\infty_C$ of infinitely differentiable functions of compact support.

Comment: @MarkViola. The derivative of distributions is based on integration by parts for the case that the distribution is given by integration against an $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ function. For that reason it's not completely wrong to use integration by parts. Moreover, $(fu)' = f'u + fu'$ as distributions, when $f \in C^\infty$ and $u$ is a distribution, and that's the basis for integration by parts.

Comment: @md2perpe I understand the history here.  But distribution theory should not be applied lightly.  We start by taking a locally integrable function $f$ and a test function $\phi\in C_C^\infty$.  The we define the distribution $\langle D_f, \phi\rangle $ is defined by the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\phi(x)\,dx$.  BUT not ALL distributions can be formed this way.  The Dirac Delta is simply NOT a function (it is a Generalized Function).  And use of an integral operator symbol to represent the functional $\langle \delta,\phi\rangle$ is abuse of notation.

Comment: @md2perpe And the space of differentiable is not an appropriate space for test functions.

Comment: @MarkViola. When I want to be certain that I do everything correctly, I use the bilinear form notation $\langle u, \varphi \rangle,$ but I often abuse notation when I think that introducing new notation will be too big of a threshold for my audience, e.g. when targeting a physics student.

Comment: @MarkViola. For compactly supported distributions one can take test functions from $C^\infty.$

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, for compactly supported distributions, $C^\infty$ is a suitable space for test functions.  And yes, the Dirac Delta is a compactly supported distribution.  But the user who posted this answer suggested that the space of differentiable functions is suitable.  Clearly that cannot be correct especially if $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: @MarkViola I'm not sure I understand all your problems, but what I will say is that $C_C^1$ , or even something weaker like $H^1$ is a good test space for $\delta$ which lives in $H^{-1/2-\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon>0$, so that one should expect that $\delta'$ lives in $H^{-3/2-\epsilon}$ so that $H^2$ or atleast $C_C^2$ is a space of good test functions.

Comment: Let me try again.  We are speaking of both $\delta$ and $\delta'$, right?.  The user who posted this answer wrote "In general, you just define $\delta'(x)$ to be the function with this property on all differentiable functions."  The space of differentiable functions is not enough.  As you wrote $C_C^1$ is a suitable space for test functions.  So, the space of continuously differentiable (not just differentiable) test functions is suitable.  At this point we are in "violent" agreement ;-).  Is $H$ meant to denote Holder space, Hilbert Space , Hardy space, or otherwise?

Comment: @MarkViola Ah, I meant to write smooth. Good catch!

Comment: @max You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: @max Max, in your development in the edited section, you omitted the $r^2\sin(\theta)$ scale factor from the differential volume $r^2\,\sin(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\,d\phi$.

Comment: @max Max, there is another issue.  Note that $\nabla \delta=\delta' \hat r$.  As you wrote.  So, we need the $\hat r$ as part of the analysis.  And note $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi \hat r \,\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi=0$$

Comment: Moreover, how does one even define $f(0,0,0)\delta(0)$?  That is, what is $\delta(0)$?  You realize that the Dirac Delta is NOT a function, and therefore, has no meaningful value at a point.

Comment: @MarkViola I think the notation $\delta(r)$ refers to a different thing, I edited the answer to reflect this. The other point was precisely that $f(0,0,0)\delta(0)$ is undefined, so that the usual definition of the derivative of a distribution doesn't make sense. I added the word formally if that makes you more happy.